# Avatar/image upload in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, avatar

I'm looking for a good jquery plugin (or simple js) for uploading avatars ...

I only need one picture at a time, if possible with drag and drop.

I've tried a lot of plugins but no one seems to fit what I want ... Too complex or not working in all browsers.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Not an answer but may help You could use a third party like http://en.gravatar.com/ that uses the users email address to show their avatar.

Answer (score 1):

This is very good Jquery Plugin which I am using at present maybe it will be useful to you.And it has a drag and drop feature included.
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Comment: It's very easy where did you find the problem?As I am using Asp.Net to implement.

Comment: i use php... but what i want it's a default image... "no picture" which i can click on to uplad or drop a file on it.. this must change as a progress bar and after uplad the image have directly to be change... and the probleme was to put the progres bar instead of the original image :s

Comment: I can do it in Asp.Net and place the default image as paperclip.

Comment: In the thumbnails.ashx file you can place the code as  Dim image As Image = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/PaperClip.Png")) then you get the default Avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[AjaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/)

Comment: with progress bar if possible :s

Comment: its doesn't support with progress bar.if you want progress bar try this http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/